# How to say "and more!" in a more professional sense

Tags: synonyms, formality, phrase-requests

We are in the process of writing an ad that details our curriculum, and the ad goes something like this - "...fall prevention, medical emergencies, AND MORE!" I keep thinking there has to be a better way to phrase that instead of "AND MORE!"  Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you don't need a synonym, you just need lower case and no exclamation point.

Comment: I agree with Jim. "...and more." is totally fine (as long as it's lowercase) in a professional setting, if there are too many items to list conveniently. Additionally, exclamation marks should really only be used for exclamatory sentences (e.g., "Oh my!" "Wow!").

Comment: Hire a copywriter and please don't ask for it for free here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would simply use "etc.", short for *et cetera* (Latin, from et "and" and cetera "the rest", neuter plural of ceterus "left over").

Answer (score 1):

You may use "among others" or "to name a few".

Answer (score 0):

The expression I would use is [*etc*.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/etc.), which is an abbreviation for [*et cetera*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/et_cetera) (literally: "and the rest").

The [APA blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/05/its-all-latin-to-me.html) lists it as one of many "Latin abbreviations common to scholarly writing", so it is accepted (and actually very widespread) in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

In answering this question, one needs to consider why the OP’s wrote ‘ . . . AND MORE!’ (in all capitals, with an exclamation  point), rather than just ‘ . . . and more’ . I assume that by writing the phrase that way, the OP is trying to convey a certain exuberant tone in which the phrase is often uttered in advertising.

Now, why do advertisers use that tone? Their purpose is twofold. On one side, they want to leave the impression that the additional, unenumerated items contain something exciting and surprising, something that is better than one might expect on the basis of an extrapolation from the enumerated items. The phrase ‘ . . . AND MORE!’ is striving to be intriguing, unlike *etc.* or *and so forth*, which suggest that the additional items are so similar to the enumerated ones that listing them all would be boring. On the other side, the advertisers also want to avoid the responsibility that they would be assuming by listing and describing the additional items. The phrase ‘ . . . AND MORE!’ enables them to do that, as it is vague enough that they cannot be accused of false advertising, if the ‘more’ turns out to be disappointing.

The phrase ‘ . . . AND MORE!’ is thus an advertising device for manipulating one’s audience, while avoiding responsibility. This implies that there **cannot** be an equivalent of that phrase that is suitable for serious, professional/academic writing, because in such writing one is expected to assume full responsibility for one’s words, and be candid with one’s audience.

The other answers on this page are, of course, correct in saying that something like *etc.* may be used in professional contexts, but that term does not capture the nuances of ‘ . . . AND MORE!’ that the OP was probably trying to convey by the use of capitals and the exclamation point.